# How to determine speeds on a WiFi network

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers

**TL;DR**

Trying to make sense of why two wifi clients with same mode have different bitrates, and report better traffic to internet than in LAN.

---

I am testing my WiFi setup **Netgear Nighthawk R7000** (FW V1.0.7.2_1.1.93) with an **Acer Travelmate B113 E** (linux 4.4.0.47-generic) and a **Samsung NP900X3E** (linux 4.4.0.45-generic).

The Wifi adapters on the laptops both are limited to `802.11a/n` max, respectively:

**B113 E**

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 01
   serial: 48:5a:b6:08:fb:a7
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-47-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:c0500000-c057ffff memory:c0580000-c058ffff
```

**NP900X3E**

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 24
   serial: c8:f7:33:e9:a3:3b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-45-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=10.0.0.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:33 memory:f0600000-f0601fff
```

The deviations in configurations I can spot here are:

- B113 kernel module config has param "link" set to "no," the other "yes."
- The WiFi adapters use different drivers.

When these are connected to the router, they for some reason have different bitrates:

**B113 E**

```
 wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"lash5g"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: DC:EF:09:B2:DC:55   
      Bit Rate=115.6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-27 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:48   Missed beacon:0
```

**NP900X3E**

```
  wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"lash5g"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: DC:EF:09:B2:DC:55   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-25 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:43   Missed beacon:0
```

---

When testing to a third laptop with `iperf` (default settings) with *100Mbps Ethernet TP link on the router switch*, the **NP900X3E** (10.0.0.5) seems to do substantially better than the **B113 E** (10.0.0.3), whose bandwidth look more like for up than down, but both still substantially worse than the bitrate reported by `iwconfig` would indicate:

```
 lash@vivace:~$ iperf -s -i1
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 Server listening on TCP port 5001
 TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 [  4] local 10.0.0.4 port 5001 connected with 10.0.0.5 port 54516
 [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
 [  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec  3.32 MBytes  27.9 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  1.0- 2.0 sec  3.52 MBytes  29.5 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  2.0- 3.0 sec  3.65 MBytes  30.6 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  3.0- 4.0 sec  3.58 MBytes  30.0 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  4.0- 5.0 sec  3.64 MBytes  30.6 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  5.0- 6.0 sec  3.53 MBytes  29.6 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  6.0- 7.0 sec  3.58 MBytes  30.0 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  7.0- 8.0 sec  3.52 MBytes  29.5 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  8.0- 9.0 sec  3.50 MBytes  29.4 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  9.0-10.0 sec  3.67 MBytes  30.8 Mbits/sec
 [  4]  0.0-10.1 sec  35.8 MBytes  29.8 Mbits/sec
 [  5] local 10.0.0.4 port 5001 connected with 10.0.0.3 port 50884
 [  5]  0.0- 1.0 sec   563 KBytes  4.61 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  1.0- 2.0 sec   557 KBytes  4.56 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  2.0- 3.0 sec   563 KBytes  4.61 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  3.0- 4.0 sec   561 KBytes  4.60 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  4.0- 5.0 sec   564 KBytes  4.62 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  5.0- 6.0 sec   557 KBytes  4.56 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  6.0- 7.0 sec   567 KBytes  4.65 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  7.0- 8.0 sec   563 KBytes  4.61 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  8.0- 9.0 sec   576 KBytes  4.71 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  9.0-10.0 sec   567 KBytes  4.65 Mbits/sec
 [  5]  0.0-10.4 sec  5.75 MBytes  4.62 Mbits/sec
```

When testing from the **NP900X3E** to the **B113 E** the throughput is the same for the latter, but only half for the former:

```
 [  3] local 10.0.0.5 port 47182 connected with 10.0.0.3 port 5001
 [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
 [  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  1.75 MBytes  14.7 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  1.75 MBytes  14.7 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  1.62 MBytes  13.6 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  1.62 MBytes  13.6 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  1.62 MBytes  13.6 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  1.62 MBytes  13.6 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  1.75 MBytes  14.7 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  1.62 MBytes  13.6 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  1.62 MBytes  13.6 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  1.62 MBytes  13.6 Mbits/sec
 [  3]  0.0-10.1 sec  16.8 MBytes  14.0 Mbits/sec
```

When testing against [speedtest.net](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli), however, they show the same throughput, *ca 50 Mbps down, 4.5 Mbit up*, which is a lot better than the LAN test.

---

The results don't quite make sense to me, as the internet test outperforms the LAN test with huge margin, and the LAN test is worse for the connection with the higher bitrate.

So what combination of measuring tools and procedures would produce more homogenous and sensible results?

---

PS: [according to this article](http://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-the-actual-real-life-speed-of-wireless-374), *100Mbps+* should only be possible with `802.11ac` which the **B113 E** does not have. How can it then be *115.6Mbps*? And why is it higher than the **NP900X3E** when they are the same mode?

Comment: What about the real world speed? Is it different too, besides the two claiming different speeds? Have you tried installing a fresh kernel? It's quite easy on Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds